# Angular js - Hide private variables from factories

Tags: angularjs, factory, encapsulation

Pls refer - http://jsfiddle.net/36qp9ekL/629/

I am using a factory method so that i can hide the implementation logic, private(pvt) variables and all the pros that factories are meant for.

If you run the code and see the console, I am able to view pvtvar1 and pvtvar2. How do I actually hide the pvt variables, implementation details.

```
app.controller("mycontroller", function($scope, myfactory) {

console.log(myfactory);

});
```

If you could tell the advantages of factories over services, would be helpful.

Comment: You really should include relevant code from that fiddle here in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, there are no privates in javascript. You are using closure to create inaccessible variables and functions. This is as good as you'l get. The console may show you (depending on the browser) properties that are defined via closure, but the important thing is, these properties aren't accessible in your code.

Advantages of a service over a factory? You can create an injectable service from a js object instead of a function so you can create services that inherit functionality. Not terribly useful since the injectable model is a replacement for inheritance in many ways but it's still an option.

I exclusively write services instead of factories but I'm using typescript in my projects (which has privates ;))

Answer (score 2):

```
app.factory("myfactory", function() {

  var pvtvar1= 3;
  var pvtvar2 = 4;
    return {
        a:function(){
        return pvtvar2 + pvtvar1;}
    }


});
```

You are declaring the object and the function on the same scope of the variables.  That's why they are shown. Here I declare the function on the object's scope. Take a look at this for more details http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/